# how do I call a php method in another Class in another file?

Tags: php, function, class, curl

I have PHP code in a file 'index.php' which includes HTML. The purpose is to authenticate with Google Directory API. This is the setup of the code:

```
<?php

// Admin Google API settings
// Portal url:


define("CALLBACK_URL", "http://localhost/los-api/google/index.php");  //Callback URL
define("AUTH_URL", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth");   //Used to get CODE (not Token!)
define("CLIENT_ID", "***.apps.googleusercontent.com");  // Personal
define("CLIENT_SECRET", "***");  // Personal
define("SCOPE", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit"); // Depends on what you want to do.
define("APIURL_DIRECTORY","https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/");  // For Google 
   Directory actions
     define("CUSTOMER_ID","***");       // Personal, see: ....? voorbeeld
   define("TOKEN_URL","https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token");   // URL to get Token (not code).

// Initiate code for access token
  if(isset($_GET["code"])){
   //DEBUG:  echo "Code: ".$_GET["code"];
    $url = TOKEN_URL."?";
  $url .= "code=".$_GET["code"];
 $url .= "&grant_type=authorization_code";
   $url .= "&client_id=". urlencode(CLIENT_ID);
   $url .= "&redirect_uri=". urlencode(CALLBACK_URL);
 $url .= "&client_secret=". urlencode(CLIENT_SECRET);

  $response = json_decode(exeCurl($url,"POST"), true);
 if(isset($response)){
   if(array_key_exists("access_token", $response)) {
    $access_token = $response;
     setcookie("LOStoken", $response['access_token'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");  // 86400 = 1 day
    }
  }
} else {

  if(isset($_POST['gettoken'])){
    $url = AUTH_URL."?";
    $url .= "response_type=code";
    $url .= "&client_id=". urlencode(CLIENT_ID);
     $url .= "&scope=". urlencode(SCOPE);
    $url .= "&redirect_uri=". urlencode(CALLBACK_URL);
```

echo exeCurl($url,"GET"); //here i want to execute the 'exeCurl' function, which exists in a file 'curl.php' in the same folder
    ?>

`curl.php`

```
<?php


namespace CURL;


class cURL
{

    // general curl method
    function exeCurl($url,$method,$body="") {
        $curl = curl_init();                      // initiate curl


        if(isset($_COOKIE["LOStoken"])){
            $headers = array(
                "Accept: */*",
                "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
                "Authorization: Bearer ". $_COOKIE["LOStoken"],
                "Connection: keep-alive",
                "Content-Length: ". strlen($body),
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "cache-control: no-cache"
            );
        } else {
            $headers = array(
                "Accept: */*",
                "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
                "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                "Content-Length: ". strlen($body),
                "Connection: keep-alive",
                "cache-control: no-cache"
            );
        }

        // Set parameters for curl
        $params = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,                              // API URL
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,                   // Return answer
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,                  // SSL, enable in production
            //CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,                          // Max redirect
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,                   // If 301, follow redirect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,                            // Max timeout
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,    // HTTP version used
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,                 // HTTP method used
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers);                   // HTTP headers

        // Combine
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $params);

        // Curl ans
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);         // fill with errors
        curl_close($curl);                // close 

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;    // if errors
        }
        if(array_key_exists("error", $response)) echo $response["error_description"];

        return $response;                 // return ans
    }


    }
```

How do I achieve this? Through inheritance? Or to import 'curl.php' , quite stuck here

Comment: `require 'curl.php';   $curlclass= new cURL; echo $curlclass->exeCurl($url,"GET");`  It's that you search?

Comment: i tried this but then I get this error message: Fatal error: Class 'curlclass' not found in C:\wamp64\www\losapi\index2.php on line 37

Comment: `$curlclass= new cURL();`  <- try this...  curl.php is on first folder on server?

Comment: yes. It is on the server folder.

Comment: Missing the namespace on the assignment? `$curlclass= new \CURL\cURL;`

Comment: @IncredibleHat this did the trick.. amazing thanks

Comment: Side note: I'd really rename the namespace, or the class... too similar ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat any suggestions?

Comment: @IncredibleHat i renamed the namespace to 'requests'

Comment: Flag answer for community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require file, active class(with namespace thanks to @IncredibleHat for suggest) and use it how you want.

```
require 'curl.php'; $curlclass= new \CURL\cURL; echo $curlclass->exeCurl($url,"GET");
```